# Running Selective Unit Tests in Jetbrains Idea or Pycharm

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test suite with multiple test methods, but I want to run only a specific test method (i.e., test_one) using Jetbrains product (e.g., Pycharm, Idea). In this case, I try to avoid using the command line approach.

How can I do that?

The unit test is as below:

```
import unittest

class TestMyMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # set up any necessary state before each test method is run
        pass

    def test_one(self):
        # test method
        print('Running test: one')

    def test_two(self):
        # test method
        print('Running test: two')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestMyMethods('test_one'))
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Running the above code generate the following

```
Testing started at 1:09 PM ...
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest C:\Users\mpx\so.py in C:\Users\Users

Running test: one
Running test: two


Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should post a new question rather than editing your existing one.

Comment: ops, the OP title seems to cover IDE in general but not specific product

Comment: Feel free to edit the title to match your original question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm, each of your tests should have a green triangle on the left next to the line numbers (this is called the gutter). Just click on the one for the test you want.

Note: you can find more details by googling "pycharm run tests" and clicking on the first link which is the documentation written by JetBrains.

Comment: @mpx I don't understand your follow up question. What do you want to modify exactly?

Comment: @mpx Probably not. You should just check the documentation of the other IDE.

Comment: @mpx I usually don't have `if __name__ == '__main__':` in my test files.